# Wavesurfer how to load some fake peaks before loading the real peaks

Tags: javascript, angular, wavesurfer.js

Let's say we have a wavesurfer-js player like this:

```
wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
   container: document.querySelector('#lovelyContainer'),
   backend: 'MediaElement',
   // ... and other configs here ...
});

peaksGenerated = false;
wavesurfer.load(url);
wavesurfer.drawBuffer();


wavesurfer.on('ready', () => {
   // audio is ready to play   
   wavesurfer.playPause();
});


wavesurfer.on('waveform-ready', () => {
  // waveform is generated
  peaksGenerated = true;
});
```

This code will play the audio on `ready` event and then it'll draw the peaks on `waveform-ready` whenever the PCM data (array of peaks) is generated. In this moment, we have a nice wave  on player.
But here is a problem. sometimes there is going to be gap between `ready` and `waveform-ready`. Audio is playing but PCM data is not generated yet and no waveform is displayed on view.
**What I'm trying to do:**
I need to display fake peaks on `ready` and then update them with the generated peaks on `waveform-ready`. How can I do that?

Comment: I want to do the same now. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: There's no option to change PCM data at this time. Btw, You can create two waveSurfer players (one for the fake and another for the generated peaks). Then show/hide them on view on `waveform-ready` event. Of course It's not a good solution but works. @jmecs

Comment: What a shame. I guess the approach you mentioned makes sense as a workaround. Can I ask you how you managed to generate the peaks from the audio before you loaded them in? I am trying to do the same server side in my node app.

Comment: According to the [document](https://wavesurfer-js.org/faq/) you can generate the peaks using [audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform) package on your machine. Then send the generated `JSON` file to the client. @jmecs